# file_get_contents to get file in your own local machine

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am currently testing my code on my local machine and I wanted it to be able to read and write to a text file I have so I have the following code:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(~/Desktop/insta_user.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Brad/Sites/App/src/App/MainBundle/Controller/InstaController.php on line 33
```

Here's the code that I have:

```
$file = '~/Desktop/insta_user.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

The file already exists on my desktop, just wondering how I can write to this file locally.

Answer (score 12):

Use a complete path:

```
$file = '/Users/yourname/Desktop/insta_user.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
```

Even if the webserver is running as your user it might not have the same environment.

Comment: I think finding the file works, now I am getting a permission denied :
 Permission denied in ......

Comment: This shows also that the web server is definitely not running as your user!

Comment: I've chmod to 777 to the file, giving it access to everyone to write to it.